RNFetchBlob crashes on build using download manager but not in emulator
export const downloadImage = async (imageUrl: string): Promise<void> => {
    const { fileName, type } = getFileNameFromUrl(imageUrl);
    const { fs } = RNFetchBlob;
    const downloadDest = `${fs.dirs.DownloadDir}/${fileName}`;

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        if (Platform.Version <= 29) {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                {
                    title: 'Storage Permission Required',
                    message:
                        'This app needs access to your storage to download images',
                    buttonPositive: 'Ok',
                },
            );

            if (granted !== PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                ToastComponent.Error(
                    'Permission Denied',
                    'Storage permission is required to download the image.',
                );

                return;
            }
        }
    }

    // Download the image using RNFetchBlob
    RNFetchBlob.config({
        addAndroidDownloads: {
            useDownloadManager: true,
            title: `${fileName} Downloaded`,
            notification: true,
            mime: type,
            mediaScannable: true,
            path: downloadDest,
        },
    })
        .fetch('GET', imageUrl)
        .then(async _ => {
            ToastComponent.Success(
                'Download Successful',
                'Image has been downloaded successfully',
            );
        })
        .catch(err => {
            ToastComponent.Error('Download Failed', err.message);
        });
};

This is my code for download image. This code works fine in emulator without crashes. But in build (apk) the image gets downloaded but still crashes.
"expo": "~51.0.39",
"react-native": "0.74.5",
"rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
Thanks in advance :)

hi Darshan, a better way to go about this would be to post the crash error also, so other devs can understand the issue better & help resolve
